# iCal complex recurring event doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

I have a script that generates ics files and some events tend to have complex recurrence rules `(i.e. every Monday between date1 and date2 except on holiday1 or holiday2 but also occurs once on randomDate1)`

Given my understanding of the spec defined [here](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html), it seems pretty straightforward to represent this as a mix between RRULE, RDATE and EXDATE

As you can see below in `My Complex Event`

- RRULE defines the usual expected recurrence: every Monday between Jan 11 and April 15
- RDATE defines one stray unusual date April 13
- EXDATE removes the occurrence on Jan 25

However, once i open this file in MS Outlook 2016, i see the event on the dates targeted by RRULE, i don't see it on the one targeted by EXDATE (which is okay) but i don't see it on the date targeted by RDATE (not okay)

I have validated my ical [here](http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/) and found no errors. So i'm wondering:
Is this an Outlook bug? Is there some order i should use for the ical properties?

I also tried importing this into Google Calendar, but instead of seeing the occurrence defined on Wednesday April 13 i saw it on Tuesday April 12. The RRULE and EXDATE worked as expected too.

Any ideas?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//dkhalife//NONSGML Dany v2.0//FR
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Dany
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Montreal
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:Cours
SUMMARY:My Complex Event
LOCATION:Location Location Location
DTSTART;TZID=America/Montreal:20160111T124500
DTEND;TZID=America/Montreal:20160111T143500
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160415
RDATE;VALUE=DATE:20160413
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20160125
UID:xxxx
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an appointment with the required recurrence pattern with exceptions and save it from Outlook as an ICS file? BTW,. I don't think Outlook uses RDATE.

Comment: I don't really know how to put additional non standard dates into Outlook. In other words, where in Outlook should i enter the date i currently have in RDATE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event has a time, but the `RDATE` and `EXDATE` values are all-day, which doesn't make sense (I outlined that few years ago in response to a [bug in KOrganizer](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=169336#c3)) and is invalid IMO (even though RFC 5545 doesn't say that explicitly).

Try to replace

```
RDATE;VALUE=DATE:20160413
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20160125
```

by

```
RDATE;TZID=America/Montreal:20160413T124500
EXDATE;TZID=America/Montreal:20160125T124500
```

Btw. the same is true for the `UNTIL` clause which MUST be specified in UTC time if your event is anchored in any time zone (this is explicitly specified in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-41)).

So your `RRULE` should look like:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160415T164500Z
```

Comment: Wow, that was it. I do remember seeing somewhere that if you don't specify the time part, it would match the same as the one indicated by DTSTART. Perhaps that was some false documentation. However, i did notice that now that the event shows up, it is treated as a separate one. (i.e. if you delete either the normal recurrence or the instance specified by RDATE, not all of the event's occurrences are deleted.) Any idea what the culprit would be ?

Comment: You've probably seen that in the context of an `RRULE`. The recurrence instances indeed inherit the start time if no other time is specified in the rule. Regarding deleting instances, that's a UI issue. Most clients I know about would ask you to whether to delete the single instance or the whole event (or all future instances). I don't use Outlook, so I can't tell if there is a way to achieve that.